# Extra qualification on member, bezier curve OPENGL

Tags: c++

I got error say **[Error] extra qualification 'bezierCurve::' on member 'calCurve' [-fpermissive]**. Could anyone explain to me why this happen? I've been looking for answer, but the I cannot solve the problem.

```
#ifndef _BEZIERCURVE_H_
#define _BEZIERCURVE_H_
#include "bezier.h"

class bezierCurve : public bezier{
   private:
    int numPoints;
    float **controlPoints;
    float **curvePoints;
    void bezierCurve::calCurve(); //and error here

   public:
    bezierCurve(int numPoints, float *points[3]);
    void bezierCurve::setShowPoints(bool showControlPoints); // I got the error here
    virtual void draw();
    ~bezierCurve();
};
  #endif
```

Comment: Why not simply `void calCurve();`?

Comment: please properly indent your code

Comment: wow. it's very helpful. now i get the error for  sscanf_s. did you now what this is for? it's said not declared @Caramiriel

Comment: @SisLove `sscanf_s()` is a Microsoft VisualC++ extension.

Comment: but why does when  i run the program, it says that sscanf_s() not declared? I already #include <cstdio> since that what i found when when searching for solution. Btw, i use DEVC++ when running the program. @Kingsley

Comment: @SisLove - what C++ compiler are you using?  As I said, `sscanf_s()` is not a standard function, so it's probably missing from your compiler.  Use plain `sscanf()` (or some other method) instead.

Comment: @Kingsley i use a program call devc++. so maybe i should just delete _s?

Comment: @SisLove - Yes, `devc++` uses the MinGW port of GCC.  So it does not support `sscanf_s()`.  Use the standard form of `sscanf()`.

Comment: when i'm deleting _s from sscanf_s(), the codes can run. but there's an output. says usage file : <infile>. I don't get it. :( @Kingsley

Comment: @SisLove - sounds like it wants an input file given as an argument.  But find that message in the code to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error because it is not valid C++ syntax.  The elephant in the room is that VisualC++ has historically not considered this an error.  But GCC has since around version 4.

Simply removing the extra qualifications fixes the code.

For example:

```
#ifndef __ANIMAL_H__
#define __ANIMAL_H__
class Animal 
{
    ...
    int  Animal::getLegCount();
    bool Animal::hasFur();
}; 
#endif
```

Is not correct, member must be defined without the `Classname::` prefix:

```
#ifndef __ANIMAL_H__
#define __ANIMAL_H__
class Animal 
{
    ...
    int  getLegCount();
    bool hasFur();
}; 
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing declarations and definitions. When you *declare* a member function, it's in the context of the class already so `classname::` is redundant. When you *define* the body of a function outside of the class, you need the `classname::` so that the compiler knows which class it belongs to.

```
class bezierCurve : public bezier{
    void setShowPoints(bool showControlPoints);
};

void bezierCurve::setShowPoints(bool showControlPoints) {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[this is what output i get. suppose it's not like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlQJY.png)

@kingsley, this shown the output when i'm running the codes after I remove _s from sscanf_s().

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful. Your answer should contain a full explanation, then a link may be included for supplemental information.

Comment: Find the `main` function in your program.  It will be processing variables named `argv` & `argc`.  Here you can see why this message is coming up.  It looks like you need to give the program an argument (input file) to run with.